# Django FormView, Return without redirecting

Tags: python, html, django, web, formview

I would like to know if it is possible to stay on the same page without having it reload to a success_url using FormView. Ideally I would it to just send a notification or do nothing at all. just process the form. if this makes sense.

my code currently looks like this in views.py

```
class Capture(FormView):
    template_name = "capture.html"
    success_url = '/'
    form_class = TestForm

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
       print("Submit Capture")
       form.save_screenshot()
       return super().form_valid(form)
```

how can I change this to not reload my page. Other libraries or methods are welcomed and not limited to using FormView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always redirect after a successful POST, to avoid any issues with double submissions (if the user presses Refresh, for example). But there's nothing to stop you redirecting back to the *same page*.

Comment: This makes sense. I was just wondering if there was a way to submit a user's name/surname and an image to the database without having to reload the page on success. I think I might not have asked the question properly and that's on me.

Comment: You could do it via Ajax, if that's what you mean.