# Django FormView dont redirect on successfull POST

Tags: python, django, django-views, chat

I'm currently writing a Chat-Application. In order to take User-Input, I use a Form and thus a FormView and a custom Form, following the Django-Docs. I have to set a success_url, but neither want to be redirected to another page on a successful POST, nor want i to reload the chat-page. How Do i go about that?

I've read the following Post: [Django FormView, Return without redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142615/django-formview-return-without-redirecting), but I dont really understand the Point of the Answer. Should I really avoid not redirecting? And if not, can I really achieve this with JQuery-Ajax? Doesn't that conflict with Django's success_url?

Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what might be causing the error

Comment: @KJTHoward There is no Error. I'ts a general question. Should I Nevertheless Post some Code? And if yes, which Code do you need?

Comment: With a normal html form, the page will be reloaded or redirected when you submit the form.  Typically, the browser will do a POST request to send the form data to the server and the server will send back a new page.  If you want to make a typical chat application, you will need to use JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your Answer @FiddleStix. The Problem is, that i want to store the messages in a database and i figured it would be the easyest, to use Django's Form-Infrastructure, so pure Javascript/Ajax is not possible. What can i do?

Comment: If you want to use Django Forms then you will have to put up with the page reloading whenever a user sends a message.  This might be acceptable.  Otherwise, I would use e.g. Django Rest Framework and some JavaScript so that Django can validate and save all of your messages and the JavaScript can handle the front end.  See, for example, [this](https://danidee10.github.io/2018/01/01/realtime-django-1.html) tuturial.

Answer (score 1):

After successful post operation, you can simply redirect URL to success url like:

```
success_url = '%s?success=1' % reverse('index_page')
return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

and in your html template check

```
{% if success == 1 %}
<h3> Data uploaded successfully</h3>
{% endif %}
```

> or

You can use django messaging and override the get_success_url method like:

```
from django.contrib import messages
def get_success_url(self):
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'form submission success')
    return reverse('index_page'))
```

and on template do like this:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```